# COUNT returns more values than when actual results are pulled

Tags: mysql, count

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT walls.wall_id FROM walls 
LEFT JOIN wall_categories ON walls.wall_id = wall_categories.wall_id 
LEFT JOIN wall_devices ON walls.wall_id = wall_devices.wall_id
WHERE wall_categories.category_id IN (1,2,3)
AND wall_devices.device_id IN (1,2,3)
AND walls.wall_id>113;
```

Above query return the result below:

[image]

And if I add COUNT to the exact same query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(walls.wall_id) FROM walls 
LEFT JOIN wall_categories ON walls.wall_id = wall_categories.wall_id 
LEFT JOIN wall_devices ON walls.wall_id = wall_devices.wall_id
WHERE wall_categories.category_id IN (1,2,3)
AND wall_devices.device_id IN (1,2,3)
AND walls.wall_id>113;
```

It returns = 14

[image]

Where can be the issue? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `WHERE` renders `LEFT JOIM wall_categories` as an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT walls.wall_id)
```

When you write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <expr>, <expr>, <expr>, ...
```

it effectively does the query as if there were no `DISTINCT` modifier, then removes all the duplicates from the result set. So when you wrote:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(walls.wall_id)
```

it simply did a normal count of all `wall_id` rows that met the criteria in the rest of the query.. This just returns a result, which is the total row count, and then `DISTINCT` removes any duplicates, which is trivial since it's just one result.

When you put the `DISTINCT` modifier inside `COUNT()`, it tells that function that it should remove duplicates while it's counting.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT walls.wall_id) FROM walls 
LEFT JOIN wall_categories ON walls.wall_id = wall_categories.wall_id 
LEFT JOIN wall_devices ON walls.wall_id = wall_devices.wall_id
WHERE wall_categories.category_id IN (1,2,3)
AND wall_devices.device_id IN (1,2,3)
AND walls.wall_id>113;
```